# ELMAH --Is There a way to identify from Error log Unhandled or userHandled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

Am using ELMAH and want to know if the Error reported by ELMAH is Unhandled or it is handled in code and logged

```
 ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);
```

Is there a way to identify it ?

Might be a simple but just curious to know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise` I use `ErrorLog.GetDefault().Log`. There is a nice example in [log4net elmah appender](https://github.com/edwinf/log4net---ELMAH-Appender/blob/master/ELMAH%20Appender%20for%20log4net/ELMAHAppender.cs) source code.